# Add empty row after specific index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named tops.
I highlighted a specific index like this:

```
rk_30 = tops[tops['ELIM']==""].index[29]
```

Further I will export this dataframe to Excel, and I want the user to quickly noticed where stops the top 30, when filtered

So I want to add an empty row after this rk_30.
Do you know how to add it at the proper place?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a clear example, but one option would be to duplicate the matches, then mask them:

```
mask = tops['ELIM']==""

out = tops.loc[tops.index.repeat(mask+1)]
out[out.index.duplicated()] = ''
```

Example output:

```
  ELIM col2
0    1    a
1    2    b
2         c
2              # added empty row
3    4    d
4    5    f
5         g
5              # added empty row
6    6    h
```

Same logic with a specific list of indices:

```
mask = tops.index.isin([2])
out = tops.loc[tops.index.repeat(mask+1)]
out[out.index.duplicated()] = ''
```

Output:

```
  ELIM col2
0    1    a
1    2    b
2         c
2              # added empty rows after index 2
3    4    d
4    5    f
5         g
6    6    h
```

Used input:

```
tops = pd.DataFrame({'ELIM': [1, 2, '', 4, 5, '', 6], 'col2': list('abcdfgh')})
```